# EF how can I refresh Context with updated values in the Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sqldependency

I have a `static` `Context` that is  doesn't refresh after updating values from the DB.

Here is a little background on how the systems work.

[image]

1. `CRUD` is done in a separate app.
2. After saving to the DB `triggers` notify the `API` on the changes.
3. After getting the changed `Entity` from the `Context` in the `API`, the `entity` still holds the old values.
4. `API` does what ever it needs to.

I'm using `EF 6.1.3` and `.net 4.6.1`

Here is the Code that handles the DB trigger using `SqlTblDependency`.

```
public class ActivityListner : DataBaseListiner<Activity>
    {
        private IActivityService _activityService;


        public ActivityListner(IActivityService actService) : base("Activity")
        {
            actService.ThrowIfNull("Activity Service not passed in DI container");
            _activityService = actService;
        }
       public override void OnChange(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Activity> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;
            //does not get latest data
            var activity = _activityService.GetActivityByID(changedEntity.ActivityID);

           //these 2 methods work but are not ideal
           // 1._activityService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IActivityService>();
           // 2. I call Context.Refresh extention method in the GetActivityByID() call above

            if (e.ChangeType == TableDependency.Enums.ChangeType.Insert)
            {
              //...
            }
            else if (e.ChangeType == TableDependency.Enums.ChangeType.Update)
            {
                //...
            }
            else if (e.ChangeType == TableDependency.Enums.ChangeType.Delete)
            {
               //...
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the extension method in the comment above

```
public static class ContextHelpers
{

    public static void RefreshContext(this MyContext ctx)
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
        var refreshableObjects = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(c => c.Entity).ToList();
        context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
    }
}
```

This is the `GetActivityByID()` method

```
    public Activity GetActivityById(Guid actId)
    {
        Context.RefreshContext();
        var act = Context.Activities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ActivityID == actId);
        return act;
    }
```

Here are the problem I would like to solve.

1. Is there a better way of disposing and re-creating a new context?
2. In step 3 above where would be the best place to new up a context? Does `Entity Framework` have an `Event` that triggers when I read from the DB where I can `Dispose and re-create a new context`? If that's not possible can I refresh the `Context` from a central location? I thought of refreshing inside of the `GenericRepository` or creating an `extension method` but I am hoping EF might have an event.

Comment: Simple answer, "Don't use a static context".  It's *bad*, very bad.  `DbContext` likes to cache data, and never release it.  The more you use it, the slower it will get. Plus they are **not** thread-safe.  `DbContext` is designed to be created as needed, and have a short life-time.  You should create one with a `using` statement, use it only long enough to complete the logical unit of work you need, then let it go.

Comment: Dependency injection. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632269.aspx).

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks but I'm already doing that. The constructor is only called once for that class, that's why I would like an EF event to new up the context without repeating myself in every method.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for the input but I don't want a using statement for every logical unit of work. That's why I asked if EF had an event or a central location where I can new up the Context.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the way Entity Framework was designed to be used. Steve's suggestion to use Dependency Injection is a valid one you should consider.  If used properly, DI can automatically instantiate a DbContext *for you* for each individual unit of work.  As it stands, a single shared instance of a `DbContext` is using Entity Framework in a  way that it wasn't designed to be used, and it WILL cause you problems (as you are seeing already).

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense You should look into the decorator pattern. Wrap your `IUnitOfWork` with a decorator to automatically create a new `DbContext` and dispose it after the uow is done.

Comment: You can fetch the context out of your IoC container when needed: `var dbContext = (ApplicationDbContext)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));`

Comment: As said above, never ever use static context. Problems you have now is just a start, and it will get worse over time. So just rewrite your code now with a proper usage of context, because later it will be harder to do. Create context (or resolve from DI, wrapped in some another class or not, doesn't matter), perform one logical operation, dispose.

Comment: Thanks Everyone I guess I just have to refactor this.